# printing the double number wrongly

Tags: c, integer, double

I want to write code that, if I input a decimal number like 612.216, I can print it as a 612216 (actually convert it to integer). However, the program changes my number to something like 2162160000000000000000001 and I don't what to do about it.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {

long double x;
scanf_s("%Lf", &x);
while (floor(x)!=x)
    x = x * 10;

printf("%Lf", x);

return 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double number =  612.216; 
    char number_as_string[20];
    snprintf(number_as_string,"%lf", number);
    for(int i = 0; number_as_string[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if(number_as_string[i] != '.')
        printf("%c", number_as_string[i]);
    return 0; 
}
```

The downside is the statically allocated array. You can use snprintf to convert the `double` into an `array of chars`.

Comment: Because of the error inherent in floating point, this would likely produce the most accurate `int` conversion.  @mhmdrzmirdamadi - you should include information like _no arrays_ in your post, not in a comment so no one else will likely see it.

Answer (score 0):

The floating point representation isn't exact so there is a very very small error in any floating point number. You could try something like this pseudocode,

while ((x - floor(x) > 0.0000000000000000001)
x *= 10;

Your math library might define a better number to use like FLT_MIN or some such ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `floor(x)!=x` check is that it doesn't take into account any inaccuracy in the representation of the input `long double` number. (In the example given, this causes an 'extra' `0.0000000000000000000001` to be added to the actual value.) See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/10871073) for more information on such inaccuracies inherent in any representation of floating-point numbers.

To fix this in your code, you can compare the difference between `floor(x)` and `x` to a given 'tolerance' - if it's less than that, consider the loop finished. You can use a value derived from the [`LDBL_EPSILON`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) constant as a typical value for that 'tolerance', though you may like to experiment with different values.

Here is a possible code solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h> // For the LDBL_EPSILON definition

int main()
{
    long double x;
    scanf_s("%Lf", &x);
    while ((x - floor(x)) > (LDBL_EPSILON * x * 10)) // Try changing the "10" value!
        x = x * 10;

    printf("%.0Lf", x); // Add the ".0" to remove the trailing ".000000" in the output

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`long double` can store many finite values *exactly*.  There are all of the form:

+/- some_integer * 2<sup>some_exponent</sup>

Since "612.216" is *not* represent-able like that (0.216 cannot be expressed as a binary fraction like 0.25 can), a nearby `long double` value was used like ~612.2160000000000000253...

Also, OP's repeated use of `x = x * 10;` adds small rounding errors and does not pose a reasonable conversion limit.

---

A alternative approach uses `LDBL_DIG` (the number of significant decimal digits that round trip from decimal text to `long double` to decimal text unchanged) and to print the `double` to a buffer.  Let `*printf()` do the heavy lifting of converting a `double` to the best decimal text.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// To print up to the LDBL_DIG most significant digits w/o trailing zeros:
void print_sig_digits(long double x) {
  //       -   d   .    ddd....ddd    e   -  expo \0
  char buf[1 + 1 + 1 + (LDBL_DIG-1) + 1 + 1 + 8   +1];
  #define e_OFFSET (1 + 1 + 1 + (LDBL_DIG-1))

  // Print using exponential format    
  snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%+.*Le", LDBL_DIG, x);
  buf[e_OFFSET] = '\0';  // End string at 'e'
  for (int i = e_OFFSET - 1; buf[i] == '0'; i--) {
    buf[i] = '\0';  // Lop off trailing '0'
  }
  buf[2] = buf[1]; // Copy first digit over '.'
  printf("%s\n", &buf[2]);
}

int main(void) {
  printf("LDBL_DIG: %d\n", LDBL_DIG);
  print_sig_digits( 612.216L);
  print_sig_digits( 1.0L/7);
  print_sig_digits( 0.000123L);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
LDBL_DIG: 18
612216
142857142857142857
123
```